# Sprite Kit: Recursive Function to Update SKShapeNodes

Tags: ios, recursion, sprite, sprite-kit

I'd like to create a SKNode which has rays (SKShapeNodes with line paths) as sub nodes. These rays should get trimmed if an obstacle occurs like a wall.

[image]

I used the following algorithm to calculate the length of a ray depending on obstacles:

```
- (CGPoint) binaryRayCastingFromRadius: (CGFloat) min toRadius: (CGFloat) max andAngle: (CGFloat) radiant {

    NSUInteger mid = min + abs(min-max)/2;

    CGPoint point = [Calculator calcPointOnCircleWithRadius: mid andRad: radiant andPosition: P(0, 0)];

    SKPhysicsBody *body = [[[self scene] physicsWorld] bodyAlongRayStart: self.position end: [self convertPoint: point toNode: self.scene]];

    if (body && body.categoryBitMask == obstacleCategory)

        return [self binaryRayCastingFromRadius: min toRadius: mid-1 andAngle: radiant];

    else if (2 < abs(min-max))

        return [self binaryRayCastingFromRadius: mid toRadius: max andAngle: radiant];

    else
        return point;
}
```

The code works pretty well. But where should I call this method to update the new length of the rays?
Should I do this in the `-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime` method? Is this an efficient way to calculate the changing length of the rays or could the recursive method call (every frame) influence the performance? Are there better solutions to do that?

Comment: When to do your processing all depends on what purpose it will end up serving. You might want to refresh your memory on this subject here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH4-SW1

Comment: How many rays are you updating?